# Implementing Wi-Fi Direct for ESP32

Tags: esp32, wifi-direct, firmware, esp-idf

First, I'm referring to the Wi-Fi P2P standard as described [here](https://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/wi-fi-direct), and specified [here](https://cse.iitkgp.ac.in/%7Ebivasm/sp_notes/wifi_direct_2.pdf). I'm not referring to the method of creating an AP and station pair.

Second, if an implementation of Wi-Fi Direct for the ESP32 already exists, please share. I've searched far and wide and have not found one.

Specifically, I want to implement Wi-Fi Direct for the ESP32-WROOM-32E. My understanding is that the hardware is theoretically capable of handling the Wi-Fi Direct standard, but that the software hasn't been written to do so. Please correct me if I'm wrong on this point.

Assuming it is possible, could Espressif's ESP-IDF be used to implement Wi-Fi Direct, using functions such as `esp_wifi_80211_tx` (described [here](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/docs/en/api-guides/wifi.rst#wi-fi-80211-packet-send))? Or would such an implementation need to written at a lower level? If so, how low? Would I need to start learning the instruction set for the Xtensa processor in the ESP32-WROOM-32E? Or is there an intermediate-level API between bare metal and ESP-IDF?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know WiFi P2P is not supported on ESP32.

Depend on your use case, Espressif has a connectless protocol called [ESP-Now](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/network/esp_now.html) which offers peer-to-peer communication among ESP32s. ESP-Now can send payload up to 250 bytes and depend on configuration, up to 20 peers. It can be run under Arduino platform or under ESP-IDF and works for both ESP8266 and ESP-32.

I have an example running on a pair of ESP-01s (ESP-8266) and did a range test that you can further read [here](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2020/05/esp-01-range-test-with-esp-now-protocol/).